# How to solve an integral using binary trees?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, integral

I am writing a program for class that takes in integrals and then solves them with the use of binary trees.

For example, we have the following input. With the integral S, exemplified as a `'|'` and top number is 4 and the bottom number is 1. The expression consists of the rest of the line:

```
1|4 x^-2 +3x+4 dx
```

How do I integrate a binary tree data structure that I create and make it solve an integral formula?

Thanks

Comment: I think you are confused. I don't believe there is any reason to use binary trees for the problem of numerical integration. Binary trees are typically used for storing ordered data.

Comment: You may be asking this question too soon. Please update the question to show what you have attempted to solve the problems, or if you have no code, your research into the topic. It is impossible to provide a concise explanation without knowing where the asker has gotten stuck.

Comment: @pcarter Chances are that the tree is used to store the interpreted inputted expression (e.g. in the question is mentioned `"1|4 x^-2 +3x+4 dx"`), but the OP should clarify and narrow the problem at hand.

Comment: This is way too broad.